# Do a periodic httpcallout from AWS and then convert response to CSV and Send it to another server using SFTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I want to read google drive file periodically and then convert it to CSV and send converted file to another server using SFTP.

Comment: OK, where are you stuck? What is your question?

Comment: I created a lambda function in node.js and calling it from Cloudwatch rule daily, In the lambda function i want to use another module named 'nodejs-box' but it is showing error:-

Comment: So maybe that should have been the question you posted then? Did you include the `nodejs-box` module in your Lambda function's deployment package?

Comment: Yes I included nodejx-box in the module but still showing the same error.